# How to combine the resulting hdf5 models into one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have ten models. Each model was created after 10 epochs were completed. Now I'm interested in how all of them can be combined into one model.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: I doubt that this is an approach that works. There's a difference between a model that has been trained for 100 epochs and 10 models that have been trained for 10 epochs each. Averaging 10 bad results does not make it a good result.

Comment: I use this code https://github.com/imlab-uiip/lung-segmentation-2d